# Использование библиотеки OpenCV в php

Tags: php, javascript, linux

Всем доброго времени суток, подскажите, как в php пользоваться библиотекой opencv? Хотя бы на примере данного кода?

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

IplImage *search_main_image = 0;

int main()
{

    char search_filename[] = "trololo.jpg";
    search_main_image = cvLoadImage(search_filename);

    // ...

    cvReleaseImage(&search_main_image);

    return 0;
}
```

Или может материалы какие есть? Я давным давно видел, как парень на пхп аутентификацию при помощи видеофона, пхп и опенсв делал, но найти не могу. Только не пугайтесь :) - у меня цели в тысячу раз проще, просто с картинки получить кое-какие важные для меня данные.

p.s. Может можно на пайтоне как-то сделать, и внедрить в php, так сказать. В какую сторону смотреть в этом случае?

p.p.s. А вообще у меня есть скрипт написанный на с++, может тоже с ним можно что-то придумать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из PHP никак. Используйте системные вызовы (exec, system, e.t.c) чтобы обратиться к вашему исполняемому файлу на c++.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/mgdm/OpenCV-for-PHP